# Regex to split a long expressions string into an array of individual expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, split, expression, angular-ng-class

I have an expression string from Angular [ngClass] directive containing multiple expressions with their corresponding key separated by a comma.

```
'background_orange':row.columnname.split(',')[4] == 1,'red:color':test==='testname','yellow:color':test==='testname'
```

When I try to split the above expression string into an array of individual expression with their using the .split(',') function it is splitting the in between the individual expressions.

**Code:**

```
var temp = "'background_orange':row.columnname.split(',')[4] == 1,'red:color':test==='testname','yellow:color':test==='testname'";

var result = temp.split(',');
console.log(result);
```

**Output:**

```
["'background_orange':row.columnname.split('", "')[4] == 1", "'red:color':test==='testname'", "'yellow:color':test==='testname'"]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
["'background_orange':row.columnname.split(',')[4] == 1", "'red:color':test==='testname'", "'yellow:color':test==='testname'"]
```

I tried to build regex to extract the individual expression but able to only extract the expression keys with the below regex

**Regex:**

```
'\b(.+?)':
```

What would be a regex to extract the above mentioned expected pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex splits your string at `,` but ignores all `,` inside strings between `"` or `'`:

```js
var temp = "'background_orange':row.columnname.split(',')[4] == 1,'red:color':test==='testname','yellow:color':test==='testname'";
var r = /(('[^']*')|("[^"]*")|[^,])+/g

var result = temp.match(r)
console.log(result);
```

Each match is a non-empty sequence of:

1. `('[^']*')` letters not being `'` between `'`
2. `("[^"]*")` same as above with `"`
3. `[^,]` a char not being `,`

Comment: Thank you @Corylus. The Regex worked and the explanation is good and simple. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`((?:.*):(?:.*))\,((?:.*):(?:.*))\,((?:.*):(?:.*))`

if the format is static the above regex format can be  used.

Comment: Hi @Uthaya, Thank you for your answer. The format is not static and adding more expression is not providing the desired output for example `'background_orange':row.columnname.split(',')[4] == 1,'red:color':test==='testname','yellow:color':test==='testname','green:color':test==='testname','blue:color':test==='testname','white:color':test==='testname'`. @Corylus regex is woking good by ignoring ',' inside quotes. Thanks for the help.